# Insert row on top of a qtablewidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I'll like to know if it's possible to insert a row on top of a qtablewidget ?
Something like:

```
ui->myqtablewidget->insertRow(0);
```

Comment: I've answered directly, though this was a simple case of Read the Documentation. Many members of StackOverflow are quite uncharitable (and not without cause) when the answer is found directly in the documentation. You should bookmark it, learn your way around it, and check it thoroughly before posting in the future. Find the Qt docs at http://doc.qt.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just a heads up - I'm answered based on the documentation and C++
>   knowledge, not direct experience with Qt.

It would seem that QTableWidget has an `insertRow()` function. You simply need to specify where you want the row placed. [Read the documentation here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#insertRow).

Thus, it would seem from the documentation, you can insert a row at the beginning ("top") of your table with that exact line of code...

```
ui->myqtablewidget->insertRow(0);
```

...assuming `ui` and `myqtablewidget` are declared properly.

Comment: I'm doing like this:
    ui->myqtablewidget->insertRow(0);
    ui->myqtablewidget->update();
    ui->myqtablewidget->item(0,1).setText("Hello");
But it doesn't work. The program stops at the setText line

Comment: That would be a separate question than the one you posted, and well outside of my scope of knowledge. I'd recommend creating a new question.